# How to print rows (adjustments) from one cube to another cube

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have two cubes lets say c1,c2 and i have to make adjustments from c2 to c1
In c1 i have

| loan_id | basis_adjutment | participant_pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 123 | 346 |

in c2 i have

| loan_id | adj_element | txn_amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | bal | 678 |
| 2345 | bal | 984 |
| 2345 | bal | 2435 |
| 2345 | gain | 676 |
| 2345 | gain | 7689 |
| 2345 | gain | 234 |

When adj_element = bal i should take the corresponding txn_amt and print in basis_adjutment and When adj_element = gain I should take the corresponding txn_amt and print in participant_pct. the joining keys is loan_id The output look like

| loan_id | basis_adjutment | participant_pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 123 | 346 |
| 2345 | 678 | 676 |
| 2345 | 984 | 7689 |
| 2345 | 2435 | 234 |

in total there should be 4 rows( 1 row from c1 and 3 rows from c2 no additional rows. ) can anyone help me out in this in hive which function should i use to acheive this

Comment: Your results have a correspondence between different rows.  However, it is unclear what that correspondence is.  Is there a column that specifies the ordering?

Comment: No there is no ordering . from the cube c1 we are getting original row and for that we are making adjustments from c2 by adding additional 3 more rows.  I dont think there is any correspondence

Comment: @meraliadeva . . . Then you cannot do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, you can use conditional aggregation and `union all`:

```
select loan_id, basis_adjutment as basis_adjutment, participant_pct
from c1
union all
select loan_id, seqnum
       max(case when adj_element = 'bal' then txn_amount end),
       max(case when adj_element = 'gain' then txn_amount end)
from (select c2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by loan_id, adj_element order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from c2
     ) c2
group by loan_id, seqnum;
```